# htaccess keep files from being downloaded

Tags: .htaccess, http, fonts, access-control

I want to protect my files on the server from being downloaded but they need to be able to be accessed from/by the server, I was wondering if that would be possible with htaccess. I mean files like "font files", "images" etc.

I have tried the above but without luck. If you know a solution with htaccess or any other way, please reply!

Comment: I don't see anything "above". Also, are you aware that if I load a page from your server, and the page has a link to an image, **I am still remotely loading the image**, and if I can't remotely download the image, I will not see any images on your web pages. Doesn't matter if the server can access them or not, since the browser isn't running on the server, it's running on my computer.

Comment: When someone accesses something via HTTP the files ARE being downloaded. Preventing that action, prevents your site from functioning.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can see this working, is if you are using a server-side language, like PHP, you could do something like this in your HTML pages:

```
<!-- Your font(s) -->
<link href='http://yoursite.com/font-file?request-token=a3DdsS2n89SDF4sdf345' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

where you create some unique token in the URL, that you automatically generate, with PHP, every time you serve an HTML page, and then save that token on the server. Then use another PHP script to serve the font file, that authenticates the token in the URL via `$_GET['request-token']`, etc. If you only allow a token to be used once, before refusing any further requests for it, you can embed the font in your HTML and any user attempts at downloading it afterwards will fail.

This isn't a completely bulletproof method, but will deter the majority of attempts to steal your font assets, etc.